# Are there theoretical limitations to the dimensions of superconductors? (non-engineering limitations)

Tags: superconductivity

Are there quantum effects that limit the possible dimensions of superconductivity(type 2) outside of engineering limits?

Ex. is it theoretically possible for a 400-500$Gm^2$ piece of superconductive material? Or a 30Mm long piece of superconductive tape?

Comment: I don't see why there would be limits to the superconductivity at large scales, but there are obvious problems about the material stability against gravitation at these scales.

Comment: Broadly speaking though, more pressure means more options for superconductive elements. H2S 203Kelv & 155GPa; H2S+CH4 287K & 267GPa.